# Why after a click on button it not call my Controller Method

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to call my controller after a button click, but it's not being called. What is the problem?

After I click on 'Add Contact' it's not calling the AddContact Method. I don't understand why it's not calling AddContact

```
 <div id="conshow">
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="contact" >
                                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                                        <thead>

                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Department</th>
                                                <th>Phone</th>
                                                <th>Email</th>
                                                <th>Contact Type</th>
                                                <th>Address</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>

                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.condata}" var="condetails">  
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{!condetails.Name}</td>
                                                <td>{!condetails.Department}</td>
                                                <td>{!condetails.Phone}</td>
                                                <td>{!condetails.Email}</td>
                                                <td>{!condetails.Level__c}</td>
                                                <td>{!condetails.MailingCity}{!condetails.MailingCountry}{!condetails.MailingPostalCode}{!condetails.MailingState}{!condetails.MailingStreet}</td>

                                                <td> 
                                                    <a data-record="{!condetails.Id}" onclick="{!c.EditContact}">Edit</a>


                                                    <!--<a class="btn  btn-primary"  press= "{!c.EditContact}" >Edit</a> -->
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            </aura:iteration>                                               
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt10"  onclick="{!c.AddContData}">    Add New Contact</a>
         </div>



AddContData:function (component,event,Helper)
{
    debugger;
 // $('#AddContacts').modal('show');
    $(document).ready(function() { 
                 $('#page-wrapper').html($('#AddContacts').html());

    });

   // alert();

},
 EditContact:function (component,event,Helper)
{
    debugger;
    helper.EditContacts(component,event,helper);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are not using an aura ui element you need to use the normal 'onclick' property instead of 'press'(press is ui:.. tag related event). so change the mark up to:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" data-backdrop="false"  onclick="{!c.AddContacts}"> Add New Contact</a>
```

Comment: thanks gopal sir I already tried it but it not work

Comment: Try removing data-backdrop="false" in anchor tag and check it.

Comment: its not work sir..

Comment: have you tried removing the 'span' inside the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

I Tried your same code and its working fine for me.
try inserting alert in the controller method.

```
({
     AddContData : function(component, event) {
                       alert('Add Contact Data');
     }
})
```

Comment: sir its work out side div but in div not work

Comment: Could you please post the code after removing confidential data if any ?

Comment: Junaid P Khadar sir i edited code plz check it

Comment: I saw the code. But I didnt find any mistake in that. Have you added static resources to the component ?

Comment: yes sir i added static resource

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out your code and the click is working. 
Maybe something else inside your "AddContData:function" is going wrong. Include a console or alert inside the function and you can make sure that the particular function is being fired.

Try this:-

```
<div class="conshow"> 
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <button onclick="{!c.AddContData}" >Add New</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yes arvind sir, its work out side div but i try it in div its not work              <div id="conshow">
                                    <div class="tab-pane" id="contact" >     //Above code here               </div></div>

Comment: You're trying to call a function on a button click, right? Then do it like this:- 
<div class="conshow"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera" aria-hidden="true"></span><button onclick="{!c.AddContData}" >Add New</button> </div> Also, I would suggest you to use meaningful names for your id/class.

Comment: I tried it but no result

Comment: Hi Pankaj, the above code did work for me. There might be some other issue in your code. Can you please share screenshots of your code (comprising this part mainly)? Not just controller, the components, as well as the controller code.

Comment: Hii Arvind , I edited code with div plz check it

Comment: Are you using any external JavaScript plugins? Especially, to render <a> tag as a button or something??

Comment: Also, hope you've closed the two divs? In the above posted code, you haven't closed them.

Comment: yes arvind i closed two div at the end

Comment: Are you using any external plugins?

Comment: no i used bootstrap.js as a static resource

Comment: Ok, you've included jQuery also as a static resource, right?

Comment: Do one thing, remove that debugger and put an alert or console instead of it.  Also, you are NOT supposed to modify a DOM element inside a controller. You should have a renderer file for that. I would advice you to go through the Salesforce Trailhead modules and also please read through the Latest Lightning Devloper Guide before you start with the devlopment. https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/lightning.pdf